# JS mobile redirect to /mobile/ instead of m

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm using this source - https://github.com/ksmiley/mobile-redirect/blob/master/mobile-redirect.js

It is currently redirecting mobile users to **m.** domain.com, however I'd like it to redirect users to domain.com **/mobile**. Something to do with the following line? How can this be adjusted to work correctly?

```
mdw.MobileRedirect.translate = function(targetView, currentView) {
  return location.href.replace(/^(https?:\/\/)(m\.)?(.+)/i, 
                                 (targetView == 'mobile' ? '$1m.$3' : '$1$3'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  mdw.MobileRedirect.translate = function(targetView, currentView) {
      return location.href.replace(/^(https?:\/\/)?([^?/]+)(.*)$/i, 
                            (targetView == 'mobile' ? '$1$2/mobile$3' : '$1$2$3'));
  }
```

Will cause 
`http://www.example.com/some/path?param=1` to become `http://www.example.com/mobile/some/path?param=1`
`example.com/some/path?param=1` to become `example.com/mobile/some/path?param=1`

EDIT: Updated, first regex was wrong.